# Arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric with positive exponents but not negative exponents

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My numeric column is set to (38,19), but I get bizarre arithmetic overflow errors.

What WORKS:

```
1a) INSERT INTO sen.numeric_table VALUES('MaxUBInt', 1844674407370955161);
1b) INSERT INTO sen.numeric_table VALUES('SmallestFloatBy10', 1.175494351e-39);
```

What DOESN'T WORK:

```
2a) INSERT INTO sen.numeric_table VALUES('MaxFloat', 3.402823466e+38);
2b) INSERT INTO sen.numeric_table VALUES('MaxFloatBy10', 3.402823466e+39);
```

What I don't understand:

1) The column should allow any input not exceeding a total of 38 digits as well as not exceeding 19 places after the decimal. Assuming this is true, why does (1b) work when I've clearly exceeded 38 total number of digits? (as well as exceeding 19 digits of precision after the decimal)

Thanks!

Comment: 1b will be rounded to fit in the max number of digits after the comma (result is probably `0`). But greater numbers lead to an overflow. And you have only 19 digits before the comma (19+19=38) which you cleary exceed with your big inputs

Answer (score 0):

Underflow doesn't cause an error in SQL server; it will just round up. There are a few good discussions about it. This one for example:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2e0ca122-ecca-4ec6-a60b-e3d4b9f51d94/underflow-does-not-cause-an-error?forum=transactsql

Comment: I can't see any reason why this answer was voted down. Could you please explain what's wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your tests in 1) and 2), it looks like you're trying to find the upper bounds for int and float and lower bounds for float using the numeric(38,19) data type. The int bounds will be determined by the scale factor (19), and the precision bounds are defined for the numeric data type (see below).

Maximum precision in SQL Server is -10^38 +1 through 10^38 –1 according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746(v=SQL.90).aspx). Minimum precision will round based on the value for `NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT`.

If this is a scientific application, you may want to read the [MSDN description of precision, length, and scale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx), especially if you are performing operations with the values stored in the numeric column.